# MongoDB slow even when using index

Tags: mongodb

I have an index called `type_1_reimbursement.reimbursement_vendor_1_reimbursement.status_1_reimbursement.employee_note_1_company_id_1_created_1` which I created with:

```
db.transaction.createIndex({ type: 1, 'reimbursement.reimbursement_vendor': 1, 'reimbursement.status': 1, 'reimbursement.employee_note': 1, company_id: 1,  created: 1 })
```

My collection has ~6 million records.

I'm trying to make this query:

```
db.transaction.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      type: 'card',
      company_id: 'google',
      'reimbursement.reimbursement_vendor': { $ne: null },
      'reimbursement.status': { $in: ['approved', 'completed'] },
      'reimbursement.employee_note': {
        $nin: [null, ''],
      },
      created: { $gte: new ISODate('2022-08-12') },
    },
  },
  {
    $sort: { created: 1 },
  },
  {
    $limit: 1,
  },
]);
```

However, it is really slow. It takes 30-60 seconds to run. Here are the explain results

```
rs [direct: primary] application> db.transaction.aggregate([ { $match: { type: 'card', company_id: 'google', 'reimbursement.reimbursement_vendor': { $ne: null }, 'reimbursement.status': { $in: ['approved', 'completed'] }, 'reimbursement.employee_note': { $nin: [null, ''] }, created: { $gte: new ISODate('2022-08-12') } } }, { $sort: { created: 1 } }, { $limit: 1 }] ).explain();
{
  explainVersion: '1',
  queryPlanner: {
    namespace: 'application.transaction',
    indexFilterSet: false,
    parsedQuery: {
      '$and': [
        { company_id: { '$eq': 'google' } },
        { type: { '$eq': 'card' } },
        { created: { '$gte': ISODate("2022-08-12T00:00:00.000Z") } },
        {
          'reimbursement.status': { '$in': [ 'approved', 'completed' ] }
        },
        {
          'reimbursement.reimbursement_vendor': { '$not': { '$eq': null } }
        },
        {
          'reimbursement.employee_note': { '$not': { '$in': [ null, '' ] } }
        }
      ]
    },
    queryHash: '812E0D0B',
    planCacheKey: 'D506B9D0',
    optimizedPipeline: true,
    maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached: false,
    maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached: false,
    maxScansToExplodeReached: false,
    winningPlan: {
      stage: 'FETCH',
      inputStage: {
        stage: 'SORT',
        sortPattern: { created: 1 },
        memLimit: 104857600,
        limitAmount: 1,
        type: 'default',
        inputStage: {
          stage: 'IXSCAN',
          keyPattern: {
            type: 1,
            'reimbursement.reimbursement_vendor': 1,
            'reimbursement.status': 1,
            'reimbursement.employee_note': 1,
            company_id: 1,
            created: 1
          },
          indexName: 'type_1_reimbursement.reimbursement_vendor_1_reimbursement.status_1_reimbursement.employee_note_1_company_id_1_created_1',
          isMultiKey: false,
          multiKeyPaths: {
            type: [],
            'reimbursement.reimbursement_vendor': [],
            'reimbursement.status': [],
            'reimbursement.employee_note': [],
            company_id: [],
            created: []
          },
          isUnique: false,
          isSparse: false,
          isPartial: false,
          indexVersion: 2,
          direction: 'forward',
          indexBounds: {
            type: [ '["card", "card"]' ],
            'reimbursement.reimbursement_vendor': [ '[MinKey, undefined)', '(null, MaxKey]' ],
            'reimbursement.status': [
              '["approved", "approved"]',
              '["completed", "completed"]'
            ],
            'reimbursement.employee_note': [ '[MinKey, undefined)', '(null, "")', '("", MaxKey]' ],
            company_id: [ '["google", "google"]' ],
            created: [
              '[new Date(1660262400000), new Date(9223372036854775807)]'
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    rejectedPlans: [
      {
        stage: 'SORT',
        sortPattern: { created: 1 },
        memLimit: 104857600,
        limitAmount: 1,
        type: 'simple',
        inputStage: {
          stage: 'FETCH',
          filter: { created: { '$gte': ISODate("2022-08-12T00:00:00.000Z") } },
          inputStage: {
            stage: 'IXSCAN',
            keyPattern: {
              type: 1,
              'reimbursement.reimbursement_vendor': 1,
              'reimbursement.status': 1,
              'reimbursement.employee_note': 1,
              company_id: 1
            },
            indexName: 'type_1_reimbursement.reimbursement_vendor_1_reimbursement.status_1_reimbursement.employee_note_1_company_id_1',
            isMultiKey: false,
            multiKeyPaths: {
              type: [],
              'reimbursement.reimbursement_vendor': [],
              'reimbursement.status': [],
              'reimbursement.employee_note': [],
              company_id: []
            },
            isUnique: false,
            isSparse: false,
            isPartial: false,
            indexVersion: 2,
            direction: 'forward',
            indexBounds: {
              type: [ '["card", "card"]' ],
              'reimbursement.reimbursement_vendor': [ '[MinKey, undefined)', '(null, MaxKey]' ],
              'reimbursement.status': [
                '["approved", "approved"]',
                '["completed", "completed"]'
              ],
              'reimbursement.employee_note': [ '[MinKey, undefined)', '(null, "")', '("", MaxKey]' ],
              company_id: [ '["google", "google"]' ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  command: {
    aggregate: 'transaction',
    pipeline: [
      {
        '$match': {
          type: 'card',
          company_id: 'google',
          'reimbursement.reimbursement_vendor': { '$ne': null },
          'reimbursement.status': { '$in': [ 'approved', 'completed' ] },
          'reimbursement.employee_note': { '$nin': [ null, '' ] },
          created: { '$gte': ISODate("2022-08-12T00:00:00.000Z") }
        }
      },
      { '$sort': { created: 1 } },
      { '$limit': 1 }
    ],
    cursor: {},
    '$db': 'application'
  },
  serverInfo: {
    host: '0ebbfaaef1f0',
    port: 27027,
    version: '6.0.4',
    gitVersion: '44ff59461c1353638a71e710f385a566bcd2f547'
  },
  serverParameters: {
    internalQueryFacetBufferSizeBytes: 104857600,
    internalQueryFacetMaxOutputDocSizeBytes: 104857600,
    internalLookupStageIntermediateDocumentMaxSizeBytes: 104857600,
    internalDocumentSourceGroupMaxMemoryBytes: 104857600,
    internalQueryMaxBlockingSortMemoryUsageBytes: 104857600,
    internalQueryProhibitBlockingMergeOnMongoS: 0,
    internalQueryMaxAddToSetBytes: 104857600,
    internalDocumentSourceSetWindowFieldsMaxMemoryBytes: 104857600
  },
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1699662284, i: 1 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary(Buffer.from("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "hex"), 0),
      keyId: Long("0")
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1699662284, i: 1 })
}
```

Under `winningPlans`, it does look like it's using the index since I see it under `IXSCAN`. However, it doesn't seem to be working given how slow it is.

Did I create the index incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for gathering and sharing your explain plan in your question directly.

> Under `winningPlans`, it does look like it's using the index since I see it under `IXSCAN`. However, it doesn't seem to be working given how slow it is.

The fact that the database is able to use an index does not automatically imply that it is able to use the index *efficiently*. We would be able to say more about the specific amount of work the database is doing if given the `"executionStats"` verbosity of the explain plan, but even without that we can still see that the current index does force it to do some extra work to satisfy the request.

Try recreating your index by changing the order of the keys as follows:

```
{ type: 1, company_id: 1, 'reimbursement.status': 1, created: 1, 'reimbursement.reimbursement_vendor': 1, 'reimbursement.employee_note': 1 }
```

This should allow the database to eliminate the blocking `SORT` stage (replacing it with a streaming `SORT_MERGE` instead) while also narrowing the amount of the index that needs to be scanned.

More general guidance on the topic can be found on the [The ESR (Equality, Sort, Range) Rule page](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/equality-sort-range-rule/) in the documentation.

Comment: OH MY GOD that worked!! Since it was in an object, I didn't think that the ordering of the keys would make a difference. Thank you!